# How to set a shiro subject as current subject in SecurityUtils?

Tags: java, jersey, shiro

I am working on shiro sessions on jetty server and jersey web services. I have created a filter which have a map like subjectMap. In this map the String is a accessToken and each authenticated token is associated with a authenticated subject. I want to make a particular subject as current session subject, so that I can directly access that subject in other controller classes like SecurityUtils.getSubject().

Is there any way to use that authenticated Shiro Subject as current Subject in any Controller?

Comment: cannot understand what you mean, `Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();` the subject should be the current authenticated subject.

Comment: @XinMeng , If you haven`t logged in you will get a new subject ,I don`t know why

Comment: If current thread don't have subject, new subject will create.[getSubject()](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.3.2/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/SecurityUtils.html#getSubject--)